# Java Processing, using an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, java, processing, invoke

I just want to know if this is possible. I've been using Javascript for 4 years as a web developer, so I'm very used to using anonymous functions in my code. Now testing out Processing, I want to see how I could do all of the stuff I normally do with Javascript.

In Javascript, I use functions like so:

```
fn.call(instance,arg1, arg2);
```

or

```
fn.apply(instance,args);
```

...however, I'm not able to do things like that in Processing.

I'm trying to call an "anonymous function" and run the function in the namespace of an instance:

```
public void resetHealth(){
    this.health = 10;
}

class Player{
    public int health;
    Player(){
        super();
        this.health = 10;
    }
}

Player p = new Player();

//where it gets prickly:

resetHealth.invoke(p);
```

Expected result: `print p.health; //returns 0`

I want to know if what I'm doing is wrong for Java. However, it may be to do with Processing.

Comment: Why is resetHealth a function outside the Player class? `this` has no context or meaning in that method now.

Comment: The reason is so I can share functions and pass them around, rather than putting the functions inside of the classes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See Java 8 [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).  But I would encourage you to simply define [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), and pass objects that implement that interface instead.  "Putting methods inside objects" is Good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the long run I recommend checking out [Daniel Shiffman's OOP Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/)

You should move your resetHealth() function inside the Player class,
then call it using dot notation (e.g. `p.resetHealth()`)

```
class Player {
  public int health;
  Player() {
    super();
    this.health = 10;
  }
  public void resetHealth() {
    this.health = 10;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Player p = new Player();

  //test, set lower health
  p.health = 3;
  println("lowed health to", p.health);

  //test, call reset health
  p.resetHealth();
  println("reset health to", p.health);
}
```

If you're already used to JavaScript you should feel right at home using [p5.js](http://p5js.org/) while still using most of the Processing goodies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that answered it! I suppose that with Java there's not much of a need for small, succinct code. I'll just make good use of class inheritance, something I also do with Javascript.

Comment: Java is a compiled language so you'll find a lot of things are tighter (like strict type casting, class structure, etc.), where as JavaScript is interpreted, so a little more flexibility in terms of dynamic types. If you want to go the java, pretend you forgot OOP and inheritance and start as if from scratch with Java. This might be easier/less confusing as there are quite a few differences between the languages. If you want to make most of your JS knowledge, I'd advise using p5.js.